# Please explain how moderncv.cls defines \maketitle

Tags: packages, moderncv, documentclass-writing

This is the package
https://github.com/mliu7/latex-moderncv

I'm trying to learn how to make packages and classes something about this package makes me confused.

On line 380

```
\newcommand*{\makecvtitle}{}
```

This makes no sense because there are no parameters however in the TeX document if you type `\makecvtitle` it creates a lovely title with name address and other info.

Please explain black magic that allows this command to make a cv title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find numerous such empty definitions inside [`moderncv.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncv.cls); not just for the title.

The structure of [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) is such that it defines (via `\newcommand`) certain fundamental constructs when you load the class

```
\documentclass[..]{moderncv}
```

Then, depending on the choice of style you want, you would call

```
\moderncvstyle{<style>}
```

The above is defined as

```
\newcommand*{\moderncvstyle}[1]{
  \RequirePackage{moderncvstyle#1}}
```

So, with a call to `\moderncvstyle{casual}`, `moderncv` loads the "package" [`moderncvstylecasual.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvstylecasual.sty), which *redefines* `\moderncv` according to its own style via

```
\renewcommand{\makecvtitle}{...}
```

This is *one* approach to writing a class: The class sets up some fundamental constructions which are then extended by loading packages related to the class; an initial `\newcommand` which is then almost immediately changed via `\renewcommand`.

Are there any advantages to this approach? Yes. It allows the user to call the class *without* loading the extensions (or packages) yet still use the basic foundation. You can now modify the construction using a standard approach: `\renewcommand{\makecvtitle}{...}`.

Any disadvantages? See above... :-| I guess it depends on the end-user. You won't know to use `\newcommand{\makecvtitle}{...}` or `\renewcommand{\makecvtitle}{...}` until you run into a problem.

A way to circumvent this (again, from the end-user's perspective) if you want to define your own styles, would be to use a TeX-like syntax; that is

```
\def\makecvtitle{...}
```

since this will overwrite the definition of `\makecvtitle` regardless of its existence.

Comment: This is very similar to David's answer, just with a little more mortar.

Comment: I liked the mortar

Answer (score 5):

That is just a default (which does nothing) It gets redefined depending on options used, for example

```
moderncv/moderncvstylebanking.sty
```

does

```
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \maketitle%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle}
```

which makes it do something.

Comment: OP, note the use of `\renew...` since the command was already defined.

Comment: Thank you for some reasons I missed the redefine in that style file.  Would you consider this process a "best Practice" for making classes and packages?